# Excel 2010 RIGHT(A1,12) :)

Tags: excel, row

Is it possible RIGHT(A(1+9), 10)?

Dragging down the RIGHT(A1, 10) will be copied to or converted to RIGHT(A10,10)  from B1 to B2?

Comment: You mean to say if i drag from b1 the formula changes in a1 ?

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** enter:

```
=RIGHT(A10,10)
```

and copy down

You also start with:

```
=RIGHT(A9,10)
```

when copied down it will change like A10, A11, A12, etc.

**EDIT**

In **B1** enter:

```
=RIGHT(INDIRECT("$A$"&9*(ROW()-1)+1),10)
```

and copy down......... **B1** will reference **A1** and **B2** will reference **A10** ,etc.

Comment: No no ... I want that  while copying right(a1,10) formula to down, could the formula change to right(a10,10)? Means copying down  not make a1 to a2 it will change to a10